# How can I hide the Task sidebar in Evolution calendar?

Tags: evolution

I would like to hide the taskbar on the right shown in Evolution Calendar.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You simply have to drag the window divider over to the right while the Evolution window is *not* maximised:

[image]

This setting will be retained on restart. Oddly enough to revert these changes you can only easily drag the window open when Evolution is *maximized*, although I suspect that this is a 'feature' of the Unity Desktop's handling of scroll bars and I have found that with a steady hand this can be circumvented:

[image]

Curious...

Comment: I confirm that on Debian (stable), you can revert the setting irrespective of whether Evolution is maximized.

Comment: This UX is not consistent. There should be an option under View -> Layout -> Show Task Bar, similar to the Mail panel, where there is an option to show the "To Do Bar."

Answer (score 0):

Using Evolution 3.44.3, this option now seems to be available under View → Layout → Show Tasks and Memos pane.

[image]